# Update models with a dynamic value

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to update all my models with a newly inserted field, for which the value is dynamically calculated, and trying to find out what is the best way to do it.

So, let's assume we have `ModelA` with the new field called `newProp`. 
The value of `newProp` is dynamically calculated for each one of `<ModelA>`.

To be more concrete, before saving a `ModelA` I am doing the following

`SchemaA.pre('save', () => { calcNewPropValue })`

and this is how `newProp` is calculated on each alteration of the model.

But how can I do this to all models?
Do I have to first `.find()` all the models I am interested in, calculate the value of `newProp` and then `.update()` each one of them individually?

*I have seen there is the `.updateMany()` function but does not seem to take dynamic props for each model.*

Is there any other better and more efficient way you would suggest to implement this (e.g function, hook, lib)?

Thanks

Comment: When you say it is `dynamic` does that mean it is a field that uses values from other fields on the model or a value set by you?

Comment: It uses values from other fields and specifically from another `Schema`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the properties needed for the dynamic part ware on the same model you could have considered the [virtual field in mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#virtualtype_VirtualType). It would do a `computed` like field etc. Only issue there is you cannot query on it but you could access it on the individual models etc.

Now since you have to go to another Schema to actually do the dynamic field I would recommend a mongoDB shell script where you would start with an aggregation with a [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get all the needed fields (via left join) and then do a for-loop setting the values of your models via [findOneAndUpdate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)